# In ASP.NET MVC5 how do I retrieve the Selected Value chosen by a user in a View from a DropDownListFor and pass it to the Controller Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

In ASP.NET MVC 5 Please could someone help me with how I determine the value that has been selected from a Select List (implemented as a @Html.DropDownListFor) in a View so I can pass it back to the Controller Method in order to select a modified list of data please? I have spent a few days browsing and trying things to no avail:
Here is what I have. I have a parent Model:

```
public class ParentEndorsementViewModel
{
    // Child Models:
    public List<VW_CMA_PRODUCT_ENDORSEMENT> VW_CMA_PRODUCT_ENDORSEMENTS { get; set; }

    // This property will hold all available Products for selection:
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Product_DropDownList { get; set; }

}
```

And the relevant “child” model is:

```
public class Product_DropDownList
{
    private Product_DropDownList(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The View has:

```
@model App_Endorsement.Models.ParentEndorsementViewModel
….
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage_Endorsement", "Endorsement", new { ParentEndorsementViewModel = @Model }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product_DropDownList, new SelectList(Model.Product_DropDownList, "Value", "Text", Model.Product_DropDownList), "Show All Products")
    <input type = "submit" value = "Send" />
}
```

The Controller method starts:

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Manage_Endorsement(ParentEndorsementViewModel In_ParentEndorsementViewModel)
    {
        var ParentEndorsementViewModel = In_ParentEndorsementViewModel;
```

As I say I want to retrieve the Selected Value that the User has chosen from within the Product_DropDownList but when the model (ParentEndorsementViewModel) arrives in the Controller it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another property on your `ParentEndorsementViewModel`, which is what will hold the *selected* value from the drop down list.  Currently your code is attempting to set the selected value to the property that contains the available items.

e.g. in the view model

```
public class ParentEndorsementViewModel
{
    // Child Models:
    public List<VW_CMA_PRODUCT_ENDORSEMENT> VW_CMA_PRODUCT_ENDORSEMENTS { get; set; }

    // This property will hold all available Products for selection:
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Product_DropDownList { get; set; }

    // NEW PROPERTY
    public int SelectedProductId { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@model App_Endorsement.Models.ParentEndorsementViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage_Endorsement", "Endorsement", new { ParentEndorsementViewModel = @Model }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

    @* CHANGE THE TARGET PROPERTY HERE *@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.Product_DropDownList, "Value", "Text", Model.Product_DropDownList), "Show All Products")
    <input type = "submit" value = "Send" />
}
```

In the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Manage_Endorsement(ParentEndorsementViewModel In_ParentEndorsementViewModel)
{
    var ParentEndorsementViewModel = In_ParentEndorsementViewModel;
    var selectedProductId = ParentEndorsementViewModel.SelectedProductId;
```

Comment: Most excellent help: thank you!!!! I am on a steep learning curve with ASP.NET, MVC, Entity Framework, LINQ and the like and have cracked any number of problems but this one had me stumped. Cheers....

Answer (score 2):

I think you have overcomplicated this somewhat. Your views main model needs both a list to populate the control and a variable to contain the selected value.

For example your model:

```
public class ParentEndorsementViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }

    public ParentEndorsementViewModel() {
        // Do this just in case you forget to instantiate the list in your first call to the view.
        ProductList = New List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

On your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, Model.ProductList)
```

When the user sends this data to back to your controller via a form POST for example, the model binder should marry up to the view model. The value selected by your user is contained in SelectedId variable.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPostBack (ParentEndorsementViewModel model) {
    var myselectedid = model.SelectedId;
    //Do whatever
}
```